# npm hummus library unix(RHEL) installation failing

Tags: unix, amazon-ec2, nodes, hummus.js

We are trying to install 'hummus' library in our server. OS: Unix - RHEL

running command:- npm i hummus

node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://hummus.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/hummus/v1.0.87/node-v64-linux-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for hummus@1.0.87 and node@10.7.0 (node-v64 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
make: Entering directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/hummus/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pdfwriter/src/deps/PDFWriter/AbstractContentContext.o
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++1y"
make: *** [Release/obj.target/pdfwriter/src/deps/PDFWriter/AbstractContentContext.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory`/usr/lib/node_modules/hummus/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/lib/node_modules/hummus/binding/hummus.node" "--module_name=hummus" "--module_path=/usr/lib/node_modules/hummus/binding" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi"

The issue appears to be that the installation is looking to download a later version than exists on the download url.

The installation is trying to download : hummus/v1.0.87/node-v64-linux-x64.tar.gz

As v64 is not listed, we get the 404 error.

By going to this link:-  https://hummus.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/

The latest version is “hummus/v1.0.87/node-v59-linux-x64.tar.gz”

There is no way to specify a specic build for installation to use.

Has anyone seen a simliar issue before and have a workaround?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gets installed hummus after following the instructions on how to make binary modules compile, follow the section relevant to your case:
https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp

Answer (score 0):

you need a compiler. there are simply no ready binaries for your env.
consult https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp for compiler.

Comment: I tried running command -> npm install -g node-gyp, it updated 3 packages. But still hummus installation is failing with the above mentioned errors.

Comment: node-gyp aint gonna help you. you need a compiler. see his instructions.

Answer (score 0):

HummusJS project now is unmantained. But I need to get an existing app I had made working on an ARM environment. I found out that using the concrete version of **node 12.14.1**, the install and compilation process of HummusJS did work. I hope it helps for anyone with the same issue.